# Apache POI: Sort rows by date

Tags: java, excel, sorting, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to create an Excel document from XML. I have a cell with date values which I am styling as a date:

```
HSSFCellStyle styleDate = workbook.createCellStyle();
HSSFDataFormat dataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();
styleDate.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("dd/mm/yyyy Hh:mm"));
styleDate.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
```

Data in excel is displayed as a date. I need to sort it by date in ascending order in the Excel document.

I know that POI does not have built in sorting functions and I cannot use Aspose Cells since I have no approval from business side for extra license costs.

**Excel File structure**:
Sheet:

```
1. Item 1: 01/01/2016 (sorted correctly using HashMap sorting)
1.1. Sub item 1: 01/01/2016 02:00 (not sorted, needs to be sorted)
1.2. Sub item 2: 01/01/2016 05:00 (not sorted, needs to be sorted)
1.3. Sub item 3: 01/01/2016 01:00 (not sorted, needs to be sorted)

2. Item 2: 02/01/2016 (sorted correctly using HashMap sorting)
2.1. Sub item 1: 02/01/2016 02:00 (not sorted, needs to be sorted)
2.2. Sub item 2: 02/01/2016 05:00 (not sorted, needs to be sorted)
2.3. Sub item 3: 02/01/2016 01:00 (not sorted, needs to be sorted)
```

**HashMap sorting**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    itemHashMap.put(getNodeValue(nodeList, i, "item"),
                                getNodeValue(nodeList, i, "itemDate"));
}
```

Comment: Why not sort the data before writing and write the rows in the expected order.

Comment: Thats what I will probably end up doing, because all other variants seem to fail. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands now, Apache POI doesn't allow an easy way to sort data in resulted excel files.

You can of course use Aspose, but that requires a license. My incoming data to be processed by Apache POI and used for end excel document was in XML format:

```
<transaction>
    <transactionDate>2015-10-23T00:00:00+03:00</transactionDate>
    <transactionAmount>23</transactionAmount>
    <transactionBatch>000</transactionBatch>
    <transactionBatchDate>2015-10-27T10:12:00+02:00</transactionBatchDate>
    <transactionServiceFee>1</transactionServiceFee>
    <transactionNetAmount>22</transactionNetAmount>
</transaction>
<transaction>
    <transactionDate>2016-02-25T11:13:59+02:00</transactionDate>
    <transactionAmount>-1000</transactionAmount>
    <transactionBatch>000</transactionBatch>
    <transactionBatchDate>2016-02-25T11:14:40+02:00</transactionBatchDate>
    <transactionServiceFee>-30</transactionServiceFee>
    <transactionNetAmount>-970</transactionNetAmount>
</transaction>
    <transaction>
    <transactionDate>2015-10-23T00:00:00+03:00</transactionDate>
    <transactionAmount>23</transactionAmount>
    <transactionBatch>001</transactionBatch>
    <transactionBatchDate>2015-10-27T10:12:00+02:00</transactionBatchDate>
    <transactionServiceFee>1</transactionServiceFee>
    <transactionNetAmount>22</transactionNetAmount>
</transaction>
<transaction>
    <transactionDate>2016-02-25T11:13:59+02:00</transactionDate>
    <transactionAmount>-1000</transactionAmount>
    <transactionBatch>001</transactionBatch>
    <transactionBatchDate>2016-02-25T11:14:40+02:00</transactionBatchDate>
    <transactionServiceFee>-30</transactionServiceFee>
    <transactionNetAmount>-970</transactionNetAmount>
</transaction>
....
```

I have to present data in the following way in result Excel:

```
1. transactionBatch 000: transactionBatchDate (sorted by date in asc.)
1.1. transaction: transactionDate (sorted by date grouped by above batch)
1.2. transaction: transactionDate (sorted by date grouped by above batch)
1.3. transaction: transactionDate (sorted by date grouped by above batch)

2. transactionBatch 001: transactionBatchDate (sorted by date in asc.)
2.1. transaction: transactionDate (sorted by date grouped by above batch)
2.2. transaction: transactionDate (sorted by date grouped by above batch)
2.3. transaction: transactionDate (sorted by date grouped by above batch)
```

In order to solve my problem I first had to sort data in XML  by Date. That was achieved by making my model implement the Comparable interface.

After I could sort by date batches like this:

```
Map<String, String> transactionBatchHashMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            transactionBatchHashMap.put(getNodeValue(nodeList, i, "transactionBatch"),
                                        getNodeValue(nodeList, i, "transactionBatchDate"));
        }

        transactionBatchHashMap = sortMapByValues(transactionBatchHashMap);
```

And then by using a simple foreach loop I could group the transactions under each batch:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : transactionBatchHashMap.entrySet()) {

            HSSFRow batchRow = spreadSheet.createRow(rowNumber);
            ...

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                String transactionBatchValue = getNodeValue(nodeList, i, "transactionBatch");
                String hashMapBatchKeyValue = entry.getKey();

                if (transactionBatchValue.equals(hashMapBatchKeyValue)) {   
                ...
```

Answer (score 5):

```
private void sortSheet(Sheet sheet, int column, int rowStart) {
 boolean sorting = true;
 int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
 while (sorting) {
    sorting = false;
    for (Row row : sheet) {
        if (row.getRowNum() < rowStart) continue;
        if (lastRow == row.getRowNum()) break;
        Row nextRow = sheet.getRow(row.getRowNum() + 1);
        if (nextRow == null) continue;
        Date firstValue = row.getCell(column).getDateCellValue() ;
        Date secondValue = nextRow.getCell(column).getDateCellValue() ;
        if (secondValue.before(firstValue)) {                    
            sheet.shiftRows(nextRow.getRowNum(), nextRow.getRowNum(), -1);
            sheet.shiftRows(row.getRowNum(), row.getRowNum(), 1);
            sorting = true;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I have data in this format: 
1. item date (sorting correctly using hashmap key value sorting)
1.1. subitem with date (not sorted)
1.2. subitem with date (not sorted)
2. item date (sorting ok as above).
I don't think it will work in such case..?

Comment: you can use `compareTo` to compare your objects.

Comment: Your data model is not very clear. Could you put a concrete example?

Comment: I have updated my initial post. I actually think that I have to create another list with key + value (I need to think, since there are dublicate keys, so I cannot use a set) for sub item sorting, since there is no official handy way for this via POI.

Comment: Are your aware that shiftRows will hide upper row when using -1 or hide bottom row when using 1 and both will left an empty row?. You need to create a temporal row to use that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert the Date objects to String. Instead, use them directly within the model. It's not the models responsibility to suggest formatting, instead use a TableCellRenderer.

Allow getValueAt to return the Date object.

Modify the table model and override the getColumnClass method and return the approiate class for the hiven columns (like Date.class).

The table, will by default, format the Date objects for you.

Comment: How can this answer have two upvotes when it refers to the Java Swing API? The questioner is trying to create an XLS spreadsheet using Apache POI not render a JTable. The answer is **completely** irrelevant.